Potential deadlock in `waitEither`'s implementation inside "Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell" book
We are given the following API interface in 8th chapter of "Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell" text,
data Async a = Async (MVar (Either SomeException a))

async :: IO a -> IO (Async a)
async action = do
  var <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO (do r <- try action; putMVar var r)
  return (Async var)

readMVar :: MVar a -> IO a
readMVar m = do
  a <- takeMVar m 
  putMVar m a
  return a

waitCatch :: Async a -> IO (Either SomeException a)
waitCatch (Async var) = readMVar var

wait :: Async a -> IO a
wait a = do
  r <- waitCatch a
  case r of
    Left e -> throwIO e
    Right a -> return a

Now if we define,
waitEither :: Async a -> Async b -> IO (Either a b)
waitEither a b = do
  m <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO $ do r <- try (fmap Left (wait a)); putMVar m r
  forkIO $ do r <- try (fmap Right (wait b)); putMVar m r
  wait (Async m)

Couldn't this lead to an issue where the putMVar of line forkIO $ do r <- try (fmap Right (wait b)); putMVar m r executes before the putMVar present inside readMVar as called by implementation of wait? For simplicity, let us assume that there are no asynchronous exceptions to worry about.
Haddock of official implementation readMVar suggest that it will receive the next call of putMVar, do we want this assumption for our example?

Hmm, I don't know how to write this as an answer, but basically yes you're right. As soon as the takeMVar finishes one of the other putMVars can execute before the one in readMVar, leading to a deadlock in waitEither. I've not read that book, I'd expect it to be an intentional flaw that gets addressed within the chapter, pretty serious flaw in the book if not.

"Haddock of official implementation readMVar suggest that it will receive the next call of putMVar". Not only the next call, it will read any already "put" value as well. So if one of the Asyncs finishes, readMVar will see it. A separate issue is: what happens if one of the Asyncs finishes, we takeMVar and then the other finishes before the putMVar inside readMVar is executed? But the official docs of readMVar in base say that it isn't implemented in terms of take/put anymore https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.20.0.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html#v:readMVar

Relevant links: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/parallel-and-concurrent/9781449335939/ch07.html https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/parallel-and-concurrent/9781449335939/ch08.html#sec_merging

Apologies for accusing you of making up waitEither on your own -- I could have sworn I searched the chapter for it and came up empty.  Anyway, it's definitely a bug, and you should consider submitting an erratum, as it appears it hasn't already been spotted.
